# Node.js child process fork: CPU affinity

Tags: javascript, node.js, fork, cpu, spawn

I am wanting to use the `child_process.fork` function in Node.js, to spawn a new process. This example also works with the `spawn` function.

To ensure that these child processes are taking advantage of all the cores on the machine evenly, I want to set their CPU affinity, thus forcing them to migrate to the desired cores.

I know how to do this in C, and in the terminal, but how would I do this in Node.js?

Comment: This strikes me as a bad idea; just let the OS scheduler do its thing.  At least try benchmarking the performance of the overall system with and without affinity.  (Depending on how your forked processes work, you could try manually changing the affinity of the forked pids from the terminal for the purposes of testing this.)

Comment: @josh3736, hmm, it might be.

Comment: @josh3736, good idea. How do you get the PID of the process?

Comment: `spawn()` returns a [`ChildProcess`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_class_childprocess) which has a [`pid` property](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_pid).

Comment: @josh3736, ah okay, thanks! Maybe put that down as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll preface this by saying that setting the processor affinity of your your process is probably a bad idea.  Every node process has a number of threads (the main V8 thread that your JS runs in plus libuv threads for doing I/O and other native stuff), and limiting the node process to a single core will necessarily slow things down.

Doing nothing and letting the OS scheduler deal with your forked processes and their threads is likely to yield better performance.

Of course, the only way to really know is to benchmark the system under load.  Test different levels of load (light, medium, high) and see what performs better.

---

I can think of two ways of setting process affinity:

1. Ugly: Use `exec()` to run `taskset` to set your process' affinity.  (Use `process.pid` for the current process, or the [`pid` property](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_pid) of the `ChildProcess` returned from `fork()`.)
2. Way better: Write a native binding to the platform API.  (How you'd do it in C.)  [This module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodeaffinity) appears to do so; is old so it may or may not work.